# Getting the 'The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.' error during an update

Tags: 8, updating

I recently updated my Drupal 8 installation, and for some crazy reason my site now displays a white screen and this line of text when I go to it:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

I have no idea why. It's driving me absolutely crazy. When I check my site's error log, I see the following error. Anyone have any clue how to fix this? I've been trying to find answers to an entire day now:

```
> Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.
> Original
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
> The service "commerce_cart.cart_subscriber" has a dependency on a
> non-existent service "messenger". in
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences()
> (line 58 of
> /home/oowxas5qe9i2/public_html/shop/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php).
>     
>     Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(Array)
> (Line: 42)
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processDefinition(Object)
> (Line: 36)
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->process(Object)
> (Line: 102)
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object)
> (Line: 587)
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile()
> (Line: 1284) Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->compileContainer() (Line: 873)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 18)
> Drupal\Core\Installer\InstallerKernel->initializeContainer() (Line:
> 465) Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 414)
> install_begin_request(Object, Array) (Line: 114)
> install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44) Additional
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
> You have requested a non-existent service "theme.manager". in
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getDefinition()
> (line 817 of
> /home/oowxas5qe9i2/public_html/shop/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php).
>     
>     Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getDefinition('theme.manager')
> (Line: 455)
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get('theme.manager')
> (Line: 674) Drupal::theme() (Line: 22)
>     _drupal_maintenance_theme() (Line: 710) drupal_maintenance_theme() (Line: 967) install_display_output(Array, Array, Array) (Line: 264)
>     _drupal_log_error(Array, 1) (Line: 570)
>     _drupal_exception_handler(Object)
```

Comment: That is odd, the `messenger` service was introduced in Drupal 8.5. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2774931. To which version did you update?

Comment: What do you mean by updated the site? Did you flush caches? Did you run database updates? Do you manage your site with Composer?